# how can i redo a search on keyup function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to dynamically redo searches as the user types them into the search field character by character. I'm fairly new to programming thus i don't know what i am doing. thanks for helping.

User/index view:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get', class:"input-append" do %>

  <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "search-query2", id:"search_on_index", placeholder: "Search for people" %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#search_on_index').keyup(function () {
          var search = <%User.paginate(page: params[:page]).search('$(this).val();')%>
          $('#listeners').replaceWith(search)
      });
  </script>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users" id="listeners">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>
```

The search works just not dynamically.

Comment: The Rails application running on your server (which may be, for instance, a computer somewhere in the cloud) takes the `views/users/index.html.erb` template, evaluates the embedded Ruby, and the result is an HTML document (which may have some JavaScript in it) which gets sent to the client.  The client (which may be, for instance, one of your user's web browsers) takes that HTML document, renders it, and evaluates the JavaScript.  So, if, for example, the JS code says to modify the HTML, your browser will do that and render the result.  In particular, the Ruby code you have inside your ...

Comment: ... JavaScript function will never work the way it seems you're expecting it to.  The feature you're trying to implement is a bit more advanced, you might want to nail down some other concepts first like the client-server model, how Rails views/controllers work and what they do, what JavaScript can and can't do on a web page, etc.  From there you want to get a handle on AJAX, how it works, what it does, and different ways to use it.  Once you know how to use AJAX, implementing the feature you're asking about will be really straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a lot of concepts wrong here. Lemme explain what you are trying to do here. But before I do so I strongly suggest that you get a good Rails book and try out couple of the applications from those books before trying things on your own. Everybody starts at your level. Theres nothing wrong in what you are trying to do :).

Firstly: Ruby code is executed only once when the page is loaded for the first time in the browser. You cannot use ruby in javascript. You can use Ruby to render javascript as you wish when you send the HTML page as a response to the request from the browser side not once after that.  So the part where you are doing `var search = <%User.paginate(page: params[:page]).search('$(this).val();')%>` is impossible to do.

You need to get these concepts right before developing. :) So get a good rails book.

Alright.

Secondly: I am assuming that your search works fine except for your keyup requirement. So Im guessing that you have your controllers and models in order. So let me explain AJAX to you.

Remember when I said you can only execute ruby code or in other words invoke a Rails Controller only once when the page is loaded? Thats true but theres a magical thing called AJAX in the javascript world. This allows you to call the Rails Application and get responses without loading the page! This is exactly what you want here. You are trying to just update the search results. You dont wanna reload the entire page. You just want to update the results as the user presses keys on the search field.

Using AJAX you can make a request to your server and get a response. So in your application, the request would be to the URL where the search form would submit if the user presses enter or submits. What would you pass as arguments to this URL? yes you guessed it right! the search field value.

Alright after getting your concepts right start here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=comments

Then you'll know what to do.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I do eventually plan reading a rails book. I've been learning as I go which is more fun for me but obviously leaves fundamental gaps.

Comment: Thats a good way to learn too. But you need some basic understanding of serverside code and client side code and the whole client-server architecture. So go for the basics first. Understand what youre doing before attempting it. You can either be a developer who just cooks up an app without knowing how it works just by copying snippets or you could spend some time understanding the concepts behind what you are trying to build and become a great developer. Nobody is perfect. Everybody doesn't understand everything.. we just have to keep going at it!.. all the best..

Answer (score 0):

var onChange = function () 
{
    alert('Checking for changes...');
};
$(this).off('keyup').on('keyup', onChange);
$(this).off('paste').on('paste', onChange);
$(this).off('cut').on('cut', onChange);
$(this).off('undo').on('undo', onChange);
$(this).off('redo').on('redo', onChange);